# What is the issue in my code causing a flawed dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So i'm trying to add 2 values as a list (1 element) per key in a dictionary, my items look like this in my file :

```
['48', '0', 2550, 1651]
['33', '9', 5400, 3601]
```

where the first 2 elements combined are the key for example 48-0 is the key.
my code:

```
def dictionary(path_to_file):
    str_map = str.maketrans("", "", " []'\n")
    data = []
    with open(path_to_file, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.translate(str_map)
            line = line.split(",")
            data.append(line)
    dict = defaultdict(list)
    for row in data:
        dict["-".join(row[:2])].append(row[2:])
    for x in list(dict.keys()):
        if dict[x] == []:
            del dict[x]
    return dict
```

part of my output :

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'[1-0': [['5400', '3601]']],
             "[1-0/[['5400', '3601]']]": [],
             '[1-1': [['2550', '1651]']],
             "[1-1/[['2550', '1651]']]": [],
```

the issue happens as can be seen when that i'm having the same key twice in a row `'[1-0': [['5400', '3601]']],` then `"[1-0/[['5400', '3601]']]": [],` what is the issue in my code causing  this

Comment: You can't have multiple entries with the same key in a dictionary, do you want to append to the list when you have a duplicate key?

Comment: you should really use `ast.literal_eval` to parse your file, not your code which fails.

Comment: Can't the issue in my code be fixed?

Comment: I am sure the issue in your code can be fixed, what he is saying is that there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jean-Francois Fabre mentioned, you should be using `ast.literal_eval` instead of trying to use a string.  Here is a simple solution:

```
import ast

dct = {}
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        item = ast.literal_eval(line)
        if (item[0] + '-' + item[1]) in dct:
            dct[item[0] + '-' + item[1]] += item[2:]
        else:
            dct[item[0] + '-' + item[1]] = item[2:]
print(dct)
```

This assumes your file looks like this:

```
['48', '0', 2550, 1651]
['33', '9', 5400, 3601]
```

Output:

```
{'48-0': [2550, 1651], '33-9': [5400, 3601]}
```

Comment: Use a `collection.defaultdict(list)` instead of a `dict` and you'll save the if/else part.

Answer (score -1):

I ran your code segments locally (Python 3) but was not able to perceive any error, with following:

`file`:

```
['48', '0', 2550, 1651]
['33', '9', 5400, 3601]
```

`so-48707926.py`:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

def dictionary(path_to_file):
    str_map = str.maketrans("", "", " []'\n")
    data = []
    with open(path_to_file, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.translate(str_map)
            line = line.split(",")
            data.append(line)
    dict = defaultdict(list)
    for row in data:
        dict["-".join(row[:2])].append(row[2:])
    for x in list(dict.keys()):
        if dict[x] == []:
            del dict[x]
    return dict

print(dictionary('file'))
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'48-0': [['2550', '1651']], '33-9': [['5400', '3601']]})
```

Please double check your input.